# Problem with Class scope, how should I resolve this?

Tags: java

I started my first java project and I get stuck in class scope. I cant initiate below code:

`if (guessAttemts = MaxGuesses) {
System.out.println("Sorry you used all your nine chances. Game Over.)`

I will be appreciate if someone will help me to clarify what I doing wrong with that code: This NewGame class look like below.

```
class NewGame {
    GuessAttempts GuessAttempts = new GuessAttempts();
        private String WordToGuess;
        private String CorrectGuesses;
        private String misses;
        int guessAttempts;
        int MAX_Guesses = 9;


    public NewGame(String WordToGuess) {
            this.WordToGuess = WordToGuess;
            CorrectGuesses = "";
            misses = "";
            guessAttempts = 0;
    }

    public boolean UserGuessing(char letter) {
        boolean isHit = WordToGuess.indexOf(letter) != -1;
        if (isHit) {
            CorrectGuesses += letter;
        } else {
            misses += letter;
        }
        guessAttempts =+ 1;
        return isHit;
    }
    if (guessAttemts = MaxGuesses) {
        System.out.println("Sorry you used all your nine chances. Game Over.");
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. `if (guessAttemts = MaxGuesses)` isn't checking if those values are equal, but instead it's assigning a value to `guessAttemts` – use `==` to compare values. 2. the code you posted isn't complete, no definition for class `GuessAttempts`. 3. don't use capitalized names for _variables_, it doesn't follow naming conventions and is confusing – so change your _variable_ `GuessAttempts` to be `guessAttempts` or `attempts`, etc. 4. there are various other compilation errors that you should address.

Comment: Hey! Best of luck with your coding journey. Now some advice..
There are some variable naming conventions in java. Avoid starting variable and method names with a capital letter.

e.g. private String wordToGuess;
public boolean userGuessing(...

you may not follow the convention, but following it helps other read your code better; and correct syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

To compare to values, you should use `==`.

That means that your if-statement should look so:

```
if (guessAttemts == MaxGuesses) {
   System.out.println("Sorry you used all your nine chances. Game Over.");
}
```

Comment: Still receive message "Cannot resolve symbol guessAttemmts" same with "(...) MaxGuesses"

Comment: @Rafał What you see "cannot resolve symbol" it means that you're trying to use a variable that you never defined.  `maxGuesses` is never defined anywhere, and no value is ever assigned to it.

Comment: Ok, so i reworked it as below:  while (guessAttempts == MAX_Guesses) {
        System.out.println("Sorry you used all your nine chances. Game Over.");
    }

Comment: But now I get while "unexpected token" and both values are Unknown class